# How to translate "never not now"?

Tags: traducción

For this phrase, from Eckhart Tolle:

> Most humans are never fully present in the now, because unconsciously
> they believe that the next moment must be more important than this
> one. But then you miss your whole life, which is never not now. And
> that’s a revelation for some people: to realize that your life is only
> ever now.

should "never not now" be translated "nunca no ahora", or something else?

Comment: Es una posibilidad, pero no es muy idiomático que digamos

Comment: [...] tu vida, que nunca es ahora no. OR que no es nunca ahora no.  It's a bit weird in both languages. It should be: which is never "not now".

Comment: Lambie: I'm new to Spanish, and putting the "no" at the end of the sentence is weird to me. Where can I find some info on this grammatical pattern?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with Lambie, for me it makes no sense in Spanish. It seems that the author is German. Maybe in that language it makes sense.
In English, I can see that he plays with the contrast between "never not now" and "only ever now". Both, "never not now" (double negation) and "only ever now", are the same in Spanish: **siempre ahora**.

> But then you miss your whole life, which is never not **now**. And that’s
> a revelation for some people: to realize that your life is only ever
> **now**.

My suggestion:

> Pero entonces te pierdes toda la vida, en la cual siempre es **ahora**. Y eso  es una revelación para alguna gente: darse cuenta de que su vida únicamente transcurre **ahora**.

"Nunca no ahora" makes no sense in Spanish. "Nunca es no-ahora" makes no sense in Spanish.

It seems that the author is trying to sell the concept of **Now**, so we maintain that repetition in my suggested translation. That repetition is lost in Tac's suggested translation with "aún no". And the whole sentence there seems unnatural in my opinion. El Poder del **Ahora**, vamos!

Comment: I agree, it's contrived even in English (even though grammatically correct), so I think simplifying by removing the double negative for translation to other languages is a sensible thing to do. Thanks for your suggested translation!

Answer (score 2):

> La mayoría de las personas nunca están completamente presentes en el ahora, porque inconscientemente creen que el momento siguiente es más importante que el presente. Pero de esta forma te perdés de toda tu vida, **la cual de ninguna manera es un ‘aún no’**. Es una revelación para muchxs: reconocer que tu vida es siempre el ‘ahora’.

Comment: Cuando dice is never not now. quiere decir que sí, es ahora. Pero utiliza ese doble negativo. áun no es not yet. Sé que podrías decir que mi espanhol está mal. Es que el inglés tambien lo está, de cierta manera. Creo que el autor lo hizo de propósito.

Comment: @Lambie por supuesto, otra posibilidad es traducirlo como “nunca es un ‘ahora no’”; ‘ahora no’ y ‘aún no’ son bastante intercambiables en general. Para esta situación, lo traduciría como ‘aún no’, creo que es más acertado y expresa mejor el propósito del autor (ser fiel a las palabras no es lo mismo que traducir).

Comment: Sí, queda bien asi.

Answer (score 2):

> La mayoría de los humanos nunca están completamente presentes en el presente, porque inconscientemente creen que el próximo momento debe ser más importante que el que viven actualmente. Pero entonces extrañas toda tu vida, que nunca es ahora.

<sub>*Source [VN](https://vivaelnetworking.com/frases/61-frases-de-eckhart-tolle-autor-de-el-poder-del-ahora/#4_Estar_completamente_presente)*</sub>